# How to add animation to navigation in flutter using Get package?

Tags: flutter

I want to change the default animation of page transition to fade transition when I go to a new route using get package, Currently I am using this command to navigate : `Get.offAllNamed(HomeScreen.routeName);`, this clears my route stack and takes me to the new page using default transition.

Is there a way I can change that animation to fading animation using Get package?

Comment: did you find any solutions?

Comment: @NamsraiKhatanbaatar No, I couldn't find any solution for it, instead of using Get package, I had to implement a custom route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a kind of transaction.

```
 Get.to(() => const RegisterView(),
                              transition: Transition.downToUp);
```

Transition is enum you can give any of this and they're different animations.
fade,
fadeIn,
rightToLeft,
leftToRight,
upToDown,
downToUp,
rightToLeftWithFade,
leftToRightWithFade,
zoom,
topLevel,
noTransition,
cupertino and so on...